# C program for first seven terms in natural logarithm. I am not getting the right answer, can anyone review the following code

Tags: c, pointers, variables, generics, types

C program for first seven terms in natural logarithm. I am not getting the right answer, can anyone review the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
float x,i,sum,result=0;
printf("Enter value of x:");
scanf("%f",&x);

for(i=2;i<=7;i++)
{
    sum = (x - 1)/x;
    result = (sum + (0.5 * pow(sum,i)));
}
printf("Sum of series of Natural Logarithm is: %0.2f",result);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: This seems like a perfect time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example I suggest you try some [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: And for future questions please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). For example you need to tell us the expected and actual behavior of your program, as well as the input you give and the expected and actual output.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: always use `double` for floating-point values unless you have a **very strong** reason to do otherwise. ("Because my teacher told me to" is only a strong reason after you ask him [and understand] why)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented the [series](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Math/lnseries.html) correctly.

- The iteration should begin at `1`
- The `0.5` is only correct for the second term
- You overwrite `result` from each term instead of summing it.

Here is the corrected code. I also changed `float` to `double`, and `i` to `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double x, sum, result = 0;
    int i;
    printf("Enter value of x: ");
    int res = scanf("%lf", &x);
    if(res != 1 || x <= 0.5)        // validate
         return 1;

    for(i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        sum = (x - 1) / x;
        result = result + pow(sum,i) / i;
    }
    printf("Sum of series of Natural Logarithm is: %f\n", result);
    printf("The library function log() calculates: %f\n", log(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Program session

```
Enter value of x: 0.75
Sum of series of Natural Logarithm is: -0.287697
The library function log() calculates: -0.287682
```